# Android Listview OnClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview with containing list rows of image and two buttons. the list loads from JSON. And i am trying to hide the button in a row which i clicked.

I tried it by calling the button onclicklistener in the getView of BaseAdapter

**The problem**

When i click on a button in a row. the buttons of some other rows get hidden. i dont see the current row button hide.

The Toast message shows the correct text of the button which i am clicking as shown in the below code

**BaseAdapter / getView**

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder holder;
newsItem = listData.get(position);
if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_single_image, null);
    }
    holder.caption1View = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnpos);

    holder.caption1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HomeListItem newsItem1 = listData.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(c,newsItem1.getCaption1(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// shows the correct position button text
             holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else {
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
}       
return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing the `holder` on first use.

Comment: i did not understand ? it is initialized

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what a ViewHolder is or how to use it. If you are using a ViewHolder, it should be a separate class that *holds the views* of each list item you are instantiating. You would define the `onClick()` within that class so that each object that is created from the class will have it's own `onClick` callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add isVisible variable to the HomeListItem class. Then add these methods

```
class HomeListItem {
...
private boolean isVisible;

private boolean isVisible() {return isVisible};
private void setIsVisible(boolean b) { isVisible = b;}
```

Add this code to the `getView()` method

```
if(HomeListItem.isVisible()){
 holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
 holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Inside your click listener you should do

```
HomeListItem newsItem1 = listData.get(position);
boolean prevVisibility = newsItem1.isVisible();
newsItem1.setIsVisible(!prevVisibility);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

So the full code

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

final ViewHolder holder;
newsItem = listData.get(position);
..
  if(newsItem.isVisible()){
     holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
     holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
holder.caption1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          boolean prevVisibility = newsItem.isVisible();
          newsItem.setIsVisible(!prevVisibility);
          notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

...
}

The problem is that ListView reuses view so when you do `holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.GONE);` it will be gone if you don't update it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the adapter reuse view. This means that when you set `caption.setVisibility(View.GONE)` on your row, you not only affect this row, but also the other row that will reuse this view.

You need to keep the indexes of the hidden buttons, or any other method that can allow you to decide if the button should be hide for a row.

Then at the end of your `getView` method add these lines.

```
if (buttonShouldBeVisibileForIndex(position)) {//<= this is the method you need to implement
     holder.caption.setVisible(View.GONE);
} else {
     holder.caption.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_single_image, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.caption1View = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnpos);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        newsItem = listData.get(position);


        holder.caption1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HomeListItem newsItem1 = listData.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(c, newsItem1.getCaption1(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// shows the correct position button text
                holder.caption1View.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: It does the same, when clicked on the button, some other rows button get hides

Comment: add `holder = new ViewHolder();` inside the if condition.

Comment: can you post your whole adapter and viewholder class.